# Installing Ubuntu using VMWare Player 5 and then ROS Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, player

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have VMWare Player 5 installed on my Windows 7 laptop. I thought it would be a simple matter of installing Ubuntu in another partition using Player and then adding Hydro Medusa on top of Ubuntu. In trying to follow the ROS instructions I have become confused. Looking at the command line entries makes it seem like a Linux OS should already be installed. It's like the chicken and egg thing. I don't know if I'm approaching this correctly. Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149086/installing-ubuntu-using-vmware-player-5-and--then-ros-hydro/) by [sdjeff57](https://answers.ros.org/users/14421/sdjeff57/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should install Ubuntu first, following Ubuntu's instructions, and once you have a working Ubuntu VM, you can the follow the ROS installation instructions to install ROS in your Ubuntu VM.

It should be noted that the name "Robot Operating System" is a bit misleading, because ROS is not a traditional operating system; it's actually a collection of libraries and communication middleware that can be used on top of an existing operating system.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1